# Mounted in Vue.js Router component happens only once and not every time i open the page

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Basically whenever i open this page i need to add the script "D3.js". When i open the first time it all works right but if i change to another page and go back to this one, the script somehow doesn't load.
I don't know, it seems like the "mounted" is executed only once.
Im new to Vue.js anyway, thank you

````
const pagina2 = {
    template: `
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
       <article class="bg-dark text-white border border-dark rounded mt-4 mb-4">
           <h2 class="px-5 text-danger">Approfondimento Pagina 2</h2>
           <div id="d3-container"></div>
           <p class="px-5">Approfondimento</p>
           <p class="px-5">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
       </article>
       <!----------Page Navigation---------->
       <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
            <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
                <li class="page-item "><router-link class="page-link text-danger bg-dark border-dark" to="/">1</router-link></li>
                <li class="page-item"><router-link class="page-link text-danger bg-dark border-dark" to="/pagina2">2</router-link></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
   `,
   mounted(){
      let D3script = document.createElement('script')
      D3script.setAttribute('src', './JS/D3.js')
      document.head.appendChild(D3script)
  }
   
}```
````

Comment: probably a horrible way to add scripts in vuejs - but without more context of how you're using vuejs, and which version, that's all I'll say

Comment: Its a simple client side website project we have to make for college corse, we just started and we are only doing basic things. I need to add the script to the page so i can show the result of a script i made with D3.js library. But i canno't find a way to add this script into my page.

Comment: add it to index.html

Comment: As @Bravo is mentioning, your code can be improved in a lot of ways. On topic: One of the reasons your mounted hook is only running the first time might be that there the component is kept alive, see: https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-components.html#keepalive The mounted and unmounted hooks are only running once then.

Comment: Doesn't work if i put in the main html.
 Anyway I dont understand the keepalive, where should i put this tag?

Comment: `mounted` is run every time the component is mounted. And a page is mounted every time its route is accessed, except when the same component is used for multiple pages. In that case, you'd have to key each page to make sure the component instance is replaced when the page is changed. Otherwise, the component from the old page is being reused for the new page. Given the above, I believe your problem was that the script was running every time the page mounted, resulting in the same script tag being appended to `<head>` multiple times. You can test by logging in `mounted`.

Answer (score 0):

Btw i solved putting the D3 code inside Vue as a method and then mounting on the app.
Thank you anyway for you time :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).